# Why does boost shared_ptr include header with close()?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I am using boost 1.49.0 and am wondering why boost::shared_ptr declares close() in the global namespace, that is this program:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
int main() {
  int h = 3;
  close(h);
  return 0;
}
```

compiles and runs. I wouldn't expect close() to be part of the shared_ptr interface.  The unintended consequence for me was tracking down a bug in my program that uses a C library with a handle based interface. Instead of calling the libary's handle close function, which had a distinct name like H5Dclose (I'm working with the hdf5 library, the C interface, not the C++ interface, in hindsight I would not have had to worry about this kind of problem with the C++ interface), I mistakenly called close instead of H5Dclose, and this ended up compiling (and calling the unix, file handle close function). It would have been nice to have gotten a compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

[It doesn't](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp). There is no symbol `close` in that header.

I'd guess some standard header used by Boost is taking advantage of the standard's leniency in making C library functions available in the global namespace.

> It would have been nice to have gotten a compiler error.

Typo'ing `close` for `H5Dclose` is, to me, way beyond expecting a compiler error. Your unit tests will have caught it anyway, right?

Comment: May be related to `BOOST_NO_IOSTREAM` not being defined.  That path appears to pull in some IO headers.

Comment: I don't think the OP claimed that `close` was _declared_ inside that header (reading the question title, specifically)

Comment: Right, I was guessing it was a side effect of some other headers getting included.  I think it would be tidier if boost::shared_ptr did not bring close() into the global namespace, but maybe that causes other problems.  At this point someone doing file I/O may be getting the declaration for close() through this header.

Comment: @user2280020: `boost::shared_ptr` isn't responsible. `close` is a POSIX function and, as such, would never be found in namespace `std` anyway.

Comment: Doesn't the example code I included show that boost::shared_ptr is responsible for declaring close in the 'global' namespace (not in namespace std, then I would have had to add a using statement to access it).

Comment: @user2280020: I fail to see why you insist `boost::shared_ptr` is responsible for anything. `close` is a POSIX function. All Boost symbols are declared in namespace `boost` and none of them are ever leaked into the global namespace for you.

Comment: Like I said, and demonstrated in the example, when I include boost/shared_ptr.hpp, the function close is in the global namespace. Without including shared_ptr, I get the expected complier error about calling close. Is your experience different? If so, maybe it is a boost version issue.

Comment: @user2280020: You're not listening to me. Boost does not declare any symbol `close`, though it may include standard headers that do. The standard allows your compiler's standard library implementation to expose standard symbols into the global namespace. Your compiler is also including some POSIX symbols in those standard headers. It is not Boost's fault. Learn the distinction between cause and effect.

Comment: Maybe this is how it has to be for boost to do its job, but couldn't boost also be doing conditional compilation based on the compiler, platform, and wrap these invasive standard headers in a details namespace?  Also, in terms of what standard headers it needs, I find it odd that I get an IO function through sharedptr.

Comment: @user2280020: Boost probably _doesn't_ need it. It likely includes some standard header that includes some other header that includes some other header that eventually results in `close` being available. No, Boost cannot wrap the inclusion of standard headers in some other namespace. For the final time, **this has _nothing_ to do with Boost.**

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'd be surprised if `close` and other POSIX functions get included via standard headers, maybe it is OK for a complier to do that, but compilers like to be tidy as well.  The only time I have used `close` is by explicitly `#include <unistd.h>` where it is declared. After searching through the boost header files, I see plenty of places where they explicitly do `#include <unistd.h>`.  One looked like it was related to POSIX features, I'm still not sure why they need it for `shared_ptr` but oh well.

Comment: @user2280020: Probably for locking around the reference counting implementation.